# Ancient mysteries of the Arab world

Tags: river-crossing

If we want to convey the lion and the sheep and feed from the bank of the river to the other how to do it?

and the lion will not eat the sheep and the sheep will not eat the feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Takes the lamb across the river to river bank B, goes back to river bank A and takes the lion across to bank B. Takes lamb from bank B before the lion eats it and goes back to bank A. Takes feed from bank A to bank B and leaves it there (lion won't eat feed), goes back to bank A and picks up lamb, returns to bank B.